# Problem loading wordpress blog on Google Chrome

Tags: wordpress, browser, google-chrome, header, themes

I was doing some tweaks with the header and stuff of my wordpress blog. And all of a sudden I just realized that Google Chrome is having issues browsing the Blog page. On the other hand its working fine on Firefox. I am not sure what went wrong, following is the error message that I receive:

> Warning: Cannot modify header
>   information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/misspass/public_html/wp-blog-header.php:3)
>   in
>   /home/misspass/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php
>   on line 890

The address of the blog is

- http://www.misspassiton.com.au

I would be obliged if anyone could help me out regarding this issue.

Comment: What is on line 3 of wp-blog-header.php?

Comment: Incidentally, your blog has the same error in Firefox and Chrome for me -- are you maybe seeing a cached page in Firefox? I doubt this is a Chrome issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me you can overwrite this file:

```
/home/misspass/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php
```

Answer (score 0):

did you modify some plugins, or write some new functions that are loaded in the functions.php of the theme directory?

Are this plugins echoing something, like debug strings. This error happens when you output something BEFORE the header() function of wordpress.

What files did you modify ? 
Examining your output there are 2 \n before the warning message, seems like an echo of a null value.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, I don't think this is a Chrome problem. Your page fails for me in Firefox, too. I'm guessing the working page you're seeing in Firefox is being cached by either Firefox or WordPress, if you have a cache turned on, server-side.

Your problem is that PHP is echoing something out to the page sometime earlier than a later call to PHP's `header()` function. Because the headers have to come first (hence the name -- they're in the head of the document), this is an error.

A trivial example would be this:

```
<?php 
    echo "Hi.";
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

This is an error because PHP outputs some of the main part of the page before it tries to send a header. If it was the other way around:

```
<?php 
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    echo "Hi.";
```

...it would be fine.

In your case, it looks like the `wp_redirect()` function is being called, which tries to send a 'Location:' header. That's what's on line 890 of pluggable.php in the latest WordPress, anyway. But that redirection is failing because something on line 3 of your wp-blog-header.php file has already output something other than a header.

You need to check the code you've changed. The error appears to be coming from line 3 on wp_blog_header.php, but that seems a bit odd, as that's not a file you should be changing in order to re-theme a WordPress blog. Is it possible you opened that file and accidentally added a few blank lines at the top, before the `<?php`? Because that could definitely have caused the problem.

Comment: I am grateful that you have shared your knowledge. The issue is almost resolved now.when I try wot visit the site entering the following URL "www.misspassiton.com.au", I see that error/warning message and when I try the following "misspassiton.com.au" the page loads fine on Chrome/Firefox/IE. But I am a little stuck in another issue when I am using IE, I can not access public_html file of wordpress blog on my FTP. If I try to access an image from a public url, it works fine on firefox but shows a cross on IE. I would be obliged if you can throw some light on this issue as well.